# .NET Crystal Report with Dataset not showing any data

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I have modified a dataset by adding two new fields.  I am able to preview data, however, even after verifying the database successfully I do not see any data in my crystal report.  Any ideas?  I have tried: 'Run Custom Tool' option, I have been able to 'Verify Database' and see my new columns in the report.  I have dragged those columns into the report and I have even verified the stored procedure that is the data source for the data set (.xsd) is being passed the correct parameters.

I don't get any errors, just a blank report.

Answer (score 0):

First use Logoff and LogOn option other wise use setDataSource Location.